# Swing Worker can't update GUI components in modal jdialog

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a modal Jdialog with a progress bar and a text area. I'm launching a Swing Worker to do some background tasks and update text area in jdialog using publish-process. However, on running the program I'm observing that even though process method is called, it's still not updating the text area in jdialog. Also, note that I'm closing the jdialog in done method of swing worker and it works fine. Can anyone tell me why gui updates from (SwingWorker's) process method are not happening?

JDialog class -

```
public class ProgressDialog extends JDialog {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private GridBagLayout gridBag;
private GridBagConstraints constraints;
private ProgressDialog.ProgressBar progressBar;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextArea textArea;

ProgressDialog(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, int numTasks) {

    super(owner,title,modal);

    gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    this.progressBar = new ProgressDialog.ProgressBar();
    this.progressBar.init(numTasks);

    this.textArea = new JTextArea(10,30);
    this.textArea.setEditable(false);
    this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.textArea);
    this.scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    this.scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    this.setLayout(gridBag);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBag.setConstraints(progressBar, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10,0,10,0);
    gridBag.setConstraints(scrollPane, constraints);


    this.add(progressBar);
    this.add(scrollPane);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(400, 300);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

class ProgressBar extends JProgressBar {

    ProgressBar() {

    }

    void init(int numTasks) {
        setMaximum(numTasks);
        setStringPainted(true);
        setValue(0);
    }

    void setProgress(int taskCompleted) {
        int totalTasks = getMaximum();
        setValue(taskCompleted);
        setString(taskCompleted+"/"+totalTasks);
    }
}

static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

GridBagLayout getGridBag() {
    return gridBag;
}

GridBagConstraints getConstraints() {
    return constraints;
}

ProgressDialog.ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
    return progressBar;
}

JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
    return scrollPane;
}

JTextArea getTextArea() {
    return textArea;
}
```

}

SwingWorker class:

```
public class SwingWorkers {

static class ConnPool extends SwingWorker<Void, TaskType<String>>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ConnPool(ProgressDialog pDialog) {
        this.pDialog = pDialog;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Runner<String> runner = new Runner<>();

        Future<TaskType<String>> fut = runner.run(new Tasks.InitResources());
        runner.shutDown();

        while(!fut.isDone()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        publish(fut.get());

        return null;
    }

    protected void process(List<TaskType<String>> results) {
        if(results.size() > 0) {
            TaskType<String> lastResult = results.get(results.size()-1);
            pDialog.getTextArea().append(lastResult.getTaskStatusMesg());
            pDialog.getTextArea().append("\n");
            pDialog.getProgressBar().setValue(results.size());
        }
    }

    protected void done() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pDialog.dispose();
    }

}
```

}

Controller code that calls Jdialog and Swingworker -

```
JFrame parent = GUI.getInstance().getFrame();
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(parent,"Working...",false,1);
        pDialog.getTextArea().append("Initializing background tasks");
        new SwingWorkers.ConnPool(pDialog).execute();
        pDialog.setVisible(true);
```

I read somewhere that once modal Jdialog is made visible EDT is blocked till it's closed again? But that still doesn't explain why done method in SwingWorker is able to close Jdialog.

**Edit:**
I know I am calling process method only once (it's supposed to be in a while loop). I intend to use publish-process mechanism for more time consuming tasks after I can get this scenario (gui updates from process method) working.

Also note that sleep in done method is used only for testing. I can reproduce the same issue without using sleep method in done method.

Answer (score 3):

One huge problem is right here:

```
protected void done() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pDialog.dispose();
}
```

The worker's `done()` method is called on the EDT or event dispatch thread, and you know what happens when you sleep this thread -- the entire GUI goes to sleep and becomes completely unresponsive. If you want to delay the disposal of the dialog and keep your GUI functioning, don't do this, and in fact ***never*** call `Thread.sleep` on the EDT.

## Option 1:

Instead is in most all other Swing delay tactics, use a Swing Timer, for example, something like this (code not tested):

```
protected void done() {
    int timerDelay = 5000;
    new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pDialog.dispose();
            ((Timer) e.getSource).stop();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If you're not familiar with use of Swing Timers, then please check out the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

## Option 2:

Put your `Thread.sleep(5000)` at the end of your `doInBackground()` method, right before `return null;`

---

Another problem: you're using the publish/process method pair but only ***once*** which defeats its purpose. Perhaps you meant to call publish within the polling while loop? Of course you can only call `get()` once, but is there another way to extract information from the running process that you're calling? If so, then the information needs to be obtained intermittently, either within the polling while loop, or by whatever process allows you to extract interim results.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestProgressDialog extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private JSpinner taskNumberSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 1, 20, 1));

    public TestProgressDialog() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Launch Dialog") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Window owner = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestProgressDialog.this);
                String title = "Dialog";
                ModalityType modal = ModalityType.MODELESS;
                int numTasks = (int) taskNumberSpinner.getValue();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(owner, title, modal, numTasks);
                pDialog.pack();
                pDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                pDialog.append("Initializing background tasks\n");
                MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker(numTasks, pDialog);
                myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new WorkerListener(pDialog));
                myWorker.execute();
                pDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }));
        add(new JLabel("Number of Tasks:"));
        add(taskNumberSpinner);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestProgressDialog mainPanel = new TestProgressDialog();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Progress Dialog");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
interface Progressable {
    void setProgress(int progress);
    void append(String text);
}
```

```
class ProgressDialog extends JDialog implements Progressable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    ProgressDialog(Window owner, String title, ModalityType modal, int nunTasks) {
        super(owner, title, modal);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setValue(progress);
    }

}
```

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private static final long MAX_DUR = 6 * 1000;
    private static final long MIN_DUR = 1000;
    private String text;

    public MyCallable(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // just wait some random delay and then return a String
        long timeout = (long) (Math.random() * MAX_DUR + MIN_DUR);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(timeout);
        return text + " time out: " + timeout;
    }

}
```

```
class WorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private Progressable progressable;

    public WorkerListener(Progressable progressable) {
        this.progressable = progressable;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName() != null && evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) { 
            int progress = (int)evt.getNewValue();
            progressable.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private Progressable progressable;
    private List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    private CompletionService<String> completionService;
    private int numTasks;
    // private BlockingQueue<Future<String>> completionQueue;


    public MyWorker(int numTasks, Progressable progressable) {
        this.numTasks = numTasks;
        this.progressable = progressable;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numTasks);
        completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(service);

        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
            futures.add(completionService.submit(new MyCallable("My Callable " + i)));
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (futures.size() > 0) {
            Future<String> future = completionService.take();
            futures.remove(future);
            int progress = (100 * (numTasks - futures.size())) / numTasks;
            progress = Math.min(100, progress);
            progress = Math.max(0, progress);
            setProgress(progress);
            if (future != null) {
                publish(future.get());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            progressable.append(chunk + "\n");
        }
    }

    public Progressable getpDialog() {
        return progressable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I added that only for testing (to ensure that jdialog doesn't disappear instantaneously). I intend to remove sleep after i get get gui updates from process method working. And it still doesn't explain why GUI updates are not happening from process method. It's called before done anyway (i verified it by using sysout messages)

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't explain gui updates in process method not working. Or am i missing something here?

Comment: @Archit: I am curious why you're using the worker's publish/process method pair, but only once **after** the while loop, and not within your polling while loop. It's a strange way to wire things.

Comment: @Archit: see addendum to answer that mentions this.

Comment: @Archit: of course you can only call `get()` once on a Future task and only when it has completed all of its actions. Are you planning on running *multiple* tasks within this SwingWorker? And if so, would the interim results be the results of each task as it completes? If so, then you don't want to use polling but rather other ways to snag the Future in your collection that has completed its work, call `get()` on it and update the GUI in publish/process.

Comment: I intend to use publish in more time consuming tasks (inside a while loop) after I can get this working. I know i can just make gui calls in swing worker's done method but I'm trying to understand how to use publish- process in Swing worker.

Comment: @Archit: you can't in this set up, as it requires some way to extract interim results. Please consider 1) getting that distracting `Thread.sleep` out of your code, as it was a red herring that only caused me (and others who might look at this) to waste our time telling you not to use it. 2) create and post a valid [mcve] that truly reproduces your problem, code that we can compile and run unaltered, code that requires no outside resources not readily available to us.

Comment: @Archit No, please don't do that as this is not fair to volunteers who put effort into trying to answer this, in this case, me. Instead [edit] this question and improve it so that it is fully answerable.

Comment: @Archit: please check out edit to answer, one with a runnable example of what I'm recommending

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've narrowed down the problem and will probably edit my original post. I don't want to write too much here but it looks like issue occurs when i use card layout in my main JFrame. I will debug further. Thanks for taking time out and responding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your Jdialog box is modal. Whenever the popup(or JDialog) is `setModal(true)` the EDT thread is blocked. That's how user will not be able to do any operation when popup with modal `true`.

You have to make it `setmodal(false)` and then update contents in popup and thereafter again make it `setmodal(true)`.